# Save periodically with AJAX

Tags: jquery

I'd like to write a code that will save content of an element either after some many characters have been typed or once so often.

I will call ajax function and send content to a script to save in the background. Just not sure how to get that count going. Here's if I count to 30, but how would it look if it were continuous typing, i.e. every 30 chars?

```
var count = 0;

$(document).on("keyup", "#target", function(count) {
     if (count > 30) {
         $.ajax({
             ...
         });
     }
     count++; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic case for modulo :)

```
var count = 0;

$(document).on("keyup", "#target", function(count) {
     if (count % 30 === 29) {
         $.ajax({
             ...
         });
     }
     count++; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the counter to 0 every time you save.

```
var count = 0;

$(document).on("keyup", "#target", function(count) {
     if (count > 30) {
         count = 0;
         $.ajax({
            ...
         });
     }
     count++; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#target", function() {
     var counter = $('#counter');
     if (parseInt(counter.val()) > 30) {
         counter.val("0");
         console.log("Send Ajax");
     }
     counter.val(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="target" placeholder="Target">
<input type="text" id="counter" value="0">
```

Or:

```js
var counter = 0;
$(document).on("keyup", "#target", function() {
     if (counter > 30) {
         counter = 0;
         console.log("Send Ajax");
     }
     counter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="target" placeholder="Target">
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use a custom event that can be triggered either by count or time interval

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#target", function(count) {
  var $input = $(this),
    count = ($input.data('count') || 0) + 1;
  if (count >= 30) {
    $input.trigger('server_update');
    count = 0;
  }
  $input.data('count', count);
}).on('server_update', '#target', function() {
  var $input = $(this);
  // no need to update server if count is zero
  if ($input.data('count')) {
    $input.data('count', 0);
    // do ajax
    console.log( this.value)
  }
});


setInterval(function() {
  $('#target').trigger('server_update');

}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="target" value="test">
```